# Milvus : train and search on separte machines

Tags: mysql, machine-learning, computer-vision, milvus

I'm using [milvus](https://milvus.io/) to make image similarity research in a dataset of around one million images.

The basic setting is :

- milvus in one docker
- mysql in an other docker
- milvus reads/writes in the mysql database.

Question : is it reasonable to have mysql running on a remote machine ? How many mysql requests does Milvus do for performing one research ?

If not, I guess that the most reasonable path is to copy the mysql docker with its data from the "train machine" to the "search machine". Correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good choice to run mysql on a remote machine. There are many mysql requests when milvus does search task.

——"If not, I guess that the most reasonable path is to copy the mysql docker with its data from the "train machine" to the "search machine". Correct ?"

——Yes.