# Milvus : where to store the "id to data" relation?

Tags: mysql, machine-learning, computer-vision

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940901/milvus-train-and-search-on-separte-machines).

I'm using [milvus](https://milvus.io) to make image similarity research in a dataset of around one million images.

When I insert an image, Milvus returns an id which is the id of that image in the milvus database (mysql).
When Milvus performs a research, it returns the id of the most similar image.

Now I have to keep track of the relation "id -> image name" to be able to present the correct image when the research is done.

What is done in the furnished examples is to store that relation in a local dictionary (or using a package like [diskcache](https://pypi.org/project/diskcache/)).

This works well when the training is done on the same machine as the research.

I want to train on one machine and make the inference on an other one.

My first idea would be to store the relation "id->name"  in a separate table on the same mysql as the rest of milvus.

Is that a good idea ?
That would cost one more mysql request after the research.

Can I make a mysql join between the milvus's table "id->vector" and my table "name->id", so that milvus returns its image id in the same time as my image name ?

Comment: At the end of the day, with milvus2-rc7 I store "id->name" and "name->id" in two separate Redis databases. Python bindings are easy to use and the redis docker-compose part is very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to store the relation "id->name" on the mysql.

But I do not recommend using mysql to store the "id->vector" relationship, because vector data is generally large and takes up more space.

By the way, it's also a good choice to use a package like diskcache to store the relation "id->name".  Because it's very covenient.